# Matching 3 tables one by one and geting a final column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables with the columns as example below:

Transaction Table (tran_table), which contains "Customer Number" value as:

```
CustomerN    Date    Usercode
```

Staff Table (staff), which contains "(staff's) Customer Number" and "PersonID" as:

```
CustomerN    PersonID  UserCode
```

And, staff title log (staff_history) by date which contains the info about whether a staff is active or left; "PersonID" and "Active" as

```
PersonID   IsActive     positionname         StartDate   EndDate     UserCode
1          Yes          branch Manager       01.01.2020  01.01.4570  daniel
1          Yes          Sales representative 15.11.2018  31.12.2019  daniel
2          No           Sales associate      01.01.2018  31.05.2020  mary
3          Yes          Intern               01.01.2018  31.12.2019  josh
3          Yes          Sales associate      01.01.2020  28.02.2020  josh
3          Yes          Sales Representative 01.03.2020  01.01.4570  josh
```

I would like to get, if the customer who make a transaction is/was our staff (left or active), a column value that contains "IsActive", as "Active";"Left" or "NULL" for non-staff transactions.

I have tried this code below with no success

```
    select  b.AccountNumber, b.CustomerName ,aa.IsActive , 

(*) (select 
(*)         top 1 aa.positionname 
(*)                 from staff_history 
(*)                     where 
(*)                         b.date between aa.StartDate and aa.EndDate 
(*)                         and (b.username=aa.UserCode)) 
(*)                             as [Title], 
     from tran_table as b 
     left join staff_history as aa  WITH (NOLOCK) ON b.UserName=aa.UserCode 
    left join staff      as ab  WITH (NOLOCK) ON b.AccountNumber=ab.AccountNumber and ab.PersonId=aa.PersonId
    where 
     aa.positionname is not null 
    order by aa.positionname
```

Edit #1 to DenStudent: Sure, the result with this code ise sth like:

```
CustomerN    Date       Usercode   IsActive

15874        01.01.2020 josh       Yes
8431         05.03.2020 mary       No
55147        07.05.2020 daniel     Yes
```

the problem here is, it matches the staff's situation who MADE the transaction instead of customer (is/was a staff or not). All usercodes belongs to a staff thus, there is no "null" value.

The result that i expect is:

```
CustomerN    Date       Usercode   IsActive

15874        01.01.2020 josh       Yes (1)
8431         05.03.2020 mary       NULL (2)
55147        07.05.2020 daniel     No (3)

(1) the customer number 15874 belongs to an active staff
(2) the customer number 8431 belongs to no a former or active staff
(3) the customer number 55147 belongs to a former staff
```

Edit #2 to Marc Guillot: there are tons of additional tables and columns. I wanted to short it to the ones that relevant to this query. however, yes, the date column in transaction table, matches with staff_history table to see the staff's title on the date of transaction.  i have added several columns and the code (with(*) signed lines) if it works with you.

Comment: Can you add a few records as an example of the result you're expecting?

Comment: Why don't you show all the columns related to the problem ?. For example, is there a date on the tran_table so you want to check the state of IsActive in staff_history for that date ?.

Comment: I have added several information. I hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say because I personally don't see what you are storing on staff_history. You are only storing the periods of activity ?, or you also store periods of inactivity ?, what happens with the EnDate for the current period ?, you leave it at null ?.

If you show us the content on those tables for your sample result, then we can help you better.

It seems that you are looking for something like this:

```
select b.AccountNumber, b.CustomerName, aa.IsActive, aa.positionname as [Title]
from tran_table as b 
     outer apply (select top 1 aa.positionname, IsActive
                  from staff_history as aa
                  where     b.date between aa.StartDate and aa.EndDate 
                        and b.username=aa.UserCode
                  order by b.StartDate desc) as aa
     left join staff as ab on b.AccountNumber=ab.AccountNumber and ab.PersonId=aa.PersonId
where aa.positionname is not null 
order by aa.positionname
```

This returns the positionname and state of activity at the day of the transaction (or null if it's not present in staff_history).

I have used `outer apply`, which is like a `left join`, but instead of using a condition you directly provide with a subquery all the records that you want to join.

Comment: I have added some info on staff history table. This is the table where staff's title and promotion history by dates. I use this table to match and see the staff's title on the transaction he/she made.

Comment: @Cemil The query I have proposed doesn't work for you ?. It looks to me that it still matches the updated info.